# Choice of state variables in circuit theory

Tags: circuit-analysis

I have been trying to get a more fundamental grasp on what a circuit is, mathematically speaking. I have read about the lumped element model, constitutive equations, and the memristor. However, I still have some doubts about what the conceptual framework is.

When talking about [memristors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memristor), people say that the state variables are voltage, current, charge and magnetic flux (or flux linkage, not sure about the distinction). Then there are 6 possible pairings of state variables, two of which are definitions, and from the rest the basic [circuit elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_element) would arise:
$$
\dot q=i, \ \ 
\dot \Phi = v \\
v = R i, \ \
\Phi = L i, \ \
q = C v, \ \
\Phi = M q
$$

However, it seems to me charge and flux linkage don't add much to the picture, since they are related to `v` and `i` by their definitions. One could say that only `v` and `i` are state variables, and the circuit elements are the usual:

$$
v = L \dot i, \ \
v = i R \iff i = Gv, \ \
i = C \dot v
$$

*Do these two models differ in any significant way?* I guess the status of the memristor within the model is a distinction. Or is it just a matter of personal preference?

*More broadly*: I've also been wondering about obtaining the minimal set of equations for a circuit, and in general trying to fit things like dependent sources, nullors (norators and nullators), mutual inductances and multi-port elements into a series of gradually more complex models, and in general about the mapping to a series of linear equations. I have found some fancy math which is probably related but I don't understand, so I guess this questions are not so trivial. Nevertheless I'd be content with some guiding principles, or any pointers to accessible material that takes a more principled approach than the usual descriptive stuff. Thanks.

**Edit:** Just for clarification, I'm talking about an axiomatic approach to the subject. Circuits as an abstraction: what mathematical structure remains of Maxwell's equations when certain assumptions are made.

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I didn't think so, because I'm interested in the theoretic, more abstract, aspects of the question, and I thought I'd be more likely to get them here. What is the policy when a question is appropriate in more than one stackexchange site?

Comment: You might find parts of [this course](http://qulab.eng.yale.edu/documents/reprints/Houches_fluctuations.pdf) interesting. The author gives a formal way of writing the equations of motion for a circuit. Note that he uses charge and flux as the basic variables.

Comment: Thank you. It relies on topics I haven't studied yet, but it seems to be in the style of what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Past experience:*

In the classes that require modeling or controlling a circuit as a set of differential equations I never had to use any state variables other than voltage and current. The caveat being that these classes never went beyond linear differential equations and used nothing more complicated than current sources, voltage sources, resistors, capacitors or inductors. If you are looking for a minimum set of equations, use the second set of equations in your question.

*From my understanding of circuit analysis:*

From my understanding you are correct, charge and flux linkages do not add much to the set of equations. An analogy would be that if you know the angular acceleration of a rock in space at every point in time, you do not need to know the angular velocity or displacement. It is not that you do  not need these values, you already have enough information to solve for them. If you have current you can integrate to find charge. If you have a voltage you can integrate to find the flux linkage.

So why are they knocking about? I believe it is for historical reasons. Charge, for example, is fairly easy to measure using Coulomb's law and and as a result early literature uses this value as the variable of interest. Present day, it helps give a more complete and perhaps more intuitive understanding of what is going on inside a circuit. (these values are also important in areas other than circuit analysis such as semiconductor research where charge affects conductance)

*So you want a more complicated model?*

If you are looking for axiomatic, perhaps starting with Maxwell's equations is a good idea. The link below shows analysis of a simple RLC circuit using these equations and might be a good starting point to see what you gain or lose by using the assumptions that allow circuit analysis to work.

http://whites.sdsmt.edu/classes/ee382/notes/382Lecture8.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In traditional and present day linear circuit theory and analysis memristors are rarely if ever considered in any practical sense because the parameter \$M\$ that relates flux and charge is difficult by any passive means to physically realize. And I'm not sure that one could engineer say with op-amps a virtual memristor without the use of complex and expensive charge and flux sensors. The other parameters \$R\$,\$L\$ and \$C\$ on the other hand are easily engineered using passive materials.

Comment: Sure, the argument for the memristor is that it's there for the sake of completeness in some respect, but that is if you take the case of the four state variables. I'm asking if giving magnetic flux and charge the status of state variables, changes the theory of circuits in any discernible way (as opposed to only having only $v$ and $i$ as state variables).